# Bulk insert failing on access denied to file with domain account

Tags: sql-server

I've got a sql server 2014 that is trying to do a bulk insert into a table that is initiated from a stored procedure. The bulk insert refers to a network file path. I've set the share to allow all "everyone" to read/write to the folder. I'm logged into my laptop and try and run the stored procedure from SSMS but it fails saying access denied trying to open the file ie the hops are:

Doesn't work "Access Denied":
SSMS on Laptop (domain User:"Domain\user1") --> SQL Server instance --> File Server

Does Work:
SSMS on Laptop (SQL User:"SQLUser1") --> SQL Server instance --> File Server

Does Work:
SSMS on SQL Server instance (domain User: "Domain\user1") --> File Server

So it works when I use SSMS on the sql server with a domain account but when I use the same domain account on my laptop it comes up with the access denied to the file.

What's happening please and how do I sort it out please?

Cheers.

Comment: Sharing: You give permissions not only to share, but do folders/files also. Check if files and folders in share resource also have everyone access.

Comment: You may also check in computer management / open files which user reads input file in fact. Is this the same account in both cases?

Comment: well... Looking at the security log of the file server it looks as if the user being passed to it is "Anonymous Logon". It's almost as if the 2 hops aren't passing on my ad details but 1 hop does.

Comment: Check what user SQL Server instance is running on. This should be a dedicated domain account. If it's NETWORK SERVICE or LOCAL SERVICE problem accessing domain resources will occure.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx SQL Auth -> SQL instance account is accessing a resource; Windows Auth -> user account is accessing a resource

Comment: Maybe there is no problem with privileges but in the way how you address remote file - don't use letter mappings like S:\data.cvs but \\fileserver1\share1\data.cvs